# Google Translate API TypeError: TranslationServiceClient.translate_text() got an unexpected keyword argument 'request'

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-translate, google-translation-api

I am using Google Translate API to translate docs and I am using their API and boy is it broken.

I am using this [link](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/advanced/translating-text-v3#translating_text) to create a function that can translate a given input text,

For this code block I am getting the following error

```
# Imports the Google Cloud Translation library
from google.cloud import translate


# Initialize Translation client
def translate_text(
text: str = "YOUR_TEXT_TO_TRANSLATE", project_id: str = "YOUR_PROJECT_ID"
) -> translate.TranslationServiceClient:
"""Translating Text."""

client = translate.TranslationServiceClient()

location = "global"

parent = f"projects/{project_id}/locations/{location}"

# Translate text from English to French
# Detail on supported types can be found here:
# https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/supported-formats
response = client.translate_text(
    request={
        "parent": parent,
        "contents": [text],
        "mime_type": "text/plain",  # mime types: text/plain, text/html
        "source_language_code": "en-US",
        "target_language_code": "fr",
    }
)

# Display the translation for each input text provided
for translation in response.translations:
    print(f"Translated text: {translation.translated_text}")

return response
```

I am getting this error and I am not sure what is going on

```
TypeError: TranslationServiceClient.translate_text() got an unexpected keyword 
argument 'request'
```

Comment: Review the API and the example: https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/translate/latest/google.cloud.translate_v3beta1.services.translation_service.TranslationServiceAsyncClient#google_cloud_translate_v3beta1_services_translation_service_TranslationServiceAsyncClient_translate_text

Comment: tried this and this code documentation is also broken
AttributeError: module 'google.cloud.translate_v3beta1' has no attribute 'TranslationServiceAsyncClient'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Terrible docs, you can just follow the definition of `translate_text()` to see how it's supposed to work now (assuming there *used* to be a param `request`), but this still sucks. https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/advanced/translate-text-advance

```
request = {
    "parent": parent,
    "contents": [text],
    "mime_type": "text/plain",  # mime types: text/plain, text/html
    "source_language_code": "en-US",
    "target_language_code": "fr",
}

response = client.translate_text(**request)
```